# How to print output with a set amount of spaces in C++

Tags: c++, format, output

I'm trying to print numbers out with a set amount of spaces in front of the numbers, like this:

```
     123
     456.789
     9.342
```

I've tried `std::setw()` but it does not print out with the set amount of whitespace that I'd like because my numbers are varying in length. Is there a function in C++ that can accomplish what I need?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to align something?  left, right, decimal?  Because a "fixed amount of spaces" is simply a string of spaces of the fixed length.

Comment: You now show 3 numbers on 3 lines, which appear to be left aligned.  My editor reports 4 spaces in front of each, but I suppose these 4 spaces are the 'formatting' hint to SO tools to show the lines as 'code'.    You should notice that these 4 numbers already have a "fixed amount of spaces in front of them", i.e. 0 spaces, so we can not tell what you want.  Please show your desired results, the 3 lines with a different "fixed amount of spaces".  And while you are at it, please at least look at [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cout << setw(numberOfSpaces) << "" << number << "\n";
```